# Android : why do I have a white padding on two sides of my ImageView after down-scaling ?

Tags: java, android, layout, imageview

I know that this kind of questions has already been asked elsewhere. But I don't understand why I have got a problem in the following specific case. Here is the very simple layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#D0D0D0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"                
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/appNameTextView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/appNameTextView"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/appImageView"
            android:text="Here is some text"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

common_ic_googleplayservices is a square image which is scaled down. Why do I have a padding (see the red area) => my image is no more square.

How to solve the problem ? (please test quickly before giving an answer :) )

Thanks !!!

Comment: 1. Fill_parent should be replaced by match parent, 2. Parent height is wrap_content, ImageView height is match_parent, this is circular dependency. This is what is giving you error. Put height and width of Imageview to fixed value.

Comment: P.S. scale type works good only when both height and width of ImageView are fixed values or match_parent. But parent must not have circular dependency again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv"
        android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="30dp"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Scaletype is not actually required when height and width are wrap_content

Comment: The image is no more scaled down to the height of the appNameTextView.

Comment: What @Regis_AG, you want Image to be size of TextView?

Comment: @Regis_AG check screenshot

Comment: Yes. See  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/appNameTextView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/appNameTextView". Does not work better if I specify a height for the ImageView (same as TextView)

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Atif but your solution does not align top and bottom of the image with the TextView  :(

Comment: I did not give any solution yet @Regis_AG, I already worked on similar design, just checking whether it will work in your case or not

Comment: Yes ! The second solution seems to work properly (by setting the width of the image equal to the height of the text). Thanks !!!

Comment: I modified your answer to keep just the solution which seems correct. And slightly modified it to show clearly that the image width is set equal to the text height.

Comment: @Regis_AG  Ok Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not directly possible with `RelativeLayout` or any other default layouts, for this you need `PercentRelativeLayout`. But I suggest not to include any additional dependencies for such Task.

Step-1: Make your UI like following

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#D0D0D0" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/appImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/appImageView"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="Here is some text"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Step-2: Make following changes in JAVA code.

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    imageView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = layoutParams.height;
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
```