# ImageView full width and variable height while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

Image could be bigger dimension than the device. I want to scale the image so that it always take full width and variable length of height , while maintaining aspect ratio.

Also I want to set specific min height of `Imageview` when it is scrolled. after that specified min height `ImageView` should be pinned.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey_dark_transparent">

        <!--
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/grey_dark_transparent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
            -->
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/wallpaper_banner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/wallpaper_placeholder" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <!-- @Banner -->

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Currently it does not maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991110/android-how-to-stretch-an-image-to-the-screen-width-while-maintaining-aspect-ra?rq=1 << i found this in related on this question page but idk, u can just get the width and height of image and set image view width and height and make it scrollable

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/42693248/5471104 , here height is equal to width, you can calculate the aspect ratio and reinitialize height accordingly. But on other note, since you are using collapsing toolbar, make width and height to match parent. This will not spoil the overall appearance of the app.

Comment: @Rico I was expecting something which can be done from XML Alone

Comment: oh i see, i hardly used xml , so afraid to use them :(

Comment: @varuog, dynamic transformations in imageview can not be done with xml alone. at least till the latest update of Android tools, it doesnt allow such high level dynamic resizing through xml. Until and unless you are willing to use PercentRelativeLayout. Let me know if you dont have problem in using Additional dependency.

Comment: @MohammedAtif no i dont have any problems with dependency. I am already using Glide though. I am not sure it could help or not to solve this.

Comment: Sorry @Varuog, i just checked, even PercentRelativeLayout helps when you have predefined aspect ratio. Dynamic changes works only through code. you can probably create a custom ImageView to handle these changes within the view

Answer (score 0):

Use    ScaleType    `android:scaleType="centerInside"` like below code. Its always handle image Aspect Ratio.

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wallpaper_banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/wallpaper_placeholder" />
```

Comment: Are you sure height should be `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`?

Comment: Did you cross check? It will take the height of the image and width of the parent by neglecting the aspect ratio

Comment: but it shouldnt take width of parent, it should take width of image as per OP

Comment: @Rico, width is `match_parent` in above xml

Comment: @Chetan unfortunately Image is stretched in width by doing this. any help?

Comment: No `ImageView` takes height of inserting image according its Aspect but image having its Aspect Ratio. Suppose  `ImageView` width is match_parent and its takes height 100 but image inside `ImageView` having its Aspect Ratio.

Comment: but arif if device dimesions are 240x480 and image dimensions are 1900x1200 the OP doesnt want to reduce the image width to 240 , or am i missing something?

Comment: Then 'ImageView' Parents having 240 width and according its width height will reduces .

Comment: @Rico, the example that you gave will practically close the app with an exception of Image too large.

Comment: no u can always add a scrollview and put image view inside and then set width accordingly

Comment: Thats is `OutOfmemory` Problem.

Comment: No @Chetan, OOM and Image too large are two different exceptions. OOM happens when RAM is full. Image too large exception happens when GPU can not resize high res image for low dp imageview.

Comment: Yes both are different but when Device does not have in-off space to show image then this exceptions comes .

Comment: And if image is taken from `drawable` then its must contain same image for all `drawable` folders with less size in.

Comment: @Chetan, If image is in drawable folder, then you know the aspect ratio before hand and this question as well as answer will not make any sense.

Comment: @MohammedAtif you are questioning for ImageTolarge and OOM. And above comment is specifc to your comments.

Comment: Yes, @Chetan, even for that point, I have handled both the exceptions, and the latter has nothing to do with the memory, its directly involved with the processing power of GPU, when I was a beginner, I used to put 1080p images for 24dp icons. It used to work in Samsung and Crash in MI devices. Because MI devices at that time had bad GPU.